# Error handling at a higher level

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, exception, error-handling

I have `try/catch` blocks at lower levels to handle most errors, but I was told we need one near the top, basically as a catch all to allow the program to continue operating correctly if there is an error. I put a `try/catch(Exception e)/finally` around everything at the top level, but we are still getting exceptions causing crashes. I've been looking at the stack trace for any clues... It starts like this (I can post more of it if that would help):

`111858 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2] DEBUG o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - could not execute statement [n/a] 
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("DATABASE"."TABLE"."COLUMN")`

The weird thing is that the rest of the stack trace never goes back to anything that is ours. It's all oracle/apache/hibernate/springframework until it ends up with:

`at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:795) [na:1.7.0]`

Any ideas why it's not going back to our code or how better to implement this "catch all"? The finally block is for some steps that we want to implement whether there is an error or not.

**Edit:** for clarity's sake and because maybe it will help, this is part of a batch that processes files every 5 minutes. The try/catch is like so:

```
try{
    //process file
}catch(Exception e){
    //log exception
}finally{
    //mark file as processed so it doesn't keep trying to reprocess a broken file
}
```

Comment: Show us some relevant code please, like the top level try catch

Comment: @ToYonos The top level try/catch is already in there. It's try{//do stuff}catch(Exception e){//log stuff} finally {//do more stuff}

Answer (score 1):

You, or a library that you are using must be spawning off a thread somewhere and it is that thread that is throwing the exception.

Your options are

1. track down the creation of that thread, and handle the exception from there
2. track down which thread group that the thread belongs to and [register an exception handler with that thread group](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html#uncaughtException%28java.lang.Thread,%20java.lang.Throwable%29)

Comment: I'm not very familiar with working with thread groups. Would 2 work if it's a library spawning a new thread?

Comment: Potentially.  There is a default thread group that gets used, but it will depend on how the thread in question was created.  I am afraid that there is not enough detail in the question to nail this down for you, I can only offer some guidence.  You can ask Java to print out a list of all threads that are in use (see the jstack command, or send a kill -3 signal to the java process), and if that does not include their thread groups then the Thread class does provide what you need to write a util to do just that.  A debugger is also very useful for inspecting this kind of information too.

Answer (score 0):

The best idea I can suggest for implementing this "catch all" is don't do it.

I would, instead, recommend [defensive programming](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming) at the class level. Each class should handle its own possible exceptions when possible. This will save you time later when something goes wrong and you have to track down where to came from.

You need to debug and find where the thread is being created and handle exceptions there.

Comment: We are trying to program defensively, but we can't think of everything. This is actually a batch that is processing files. The idea is that if there is a problem with a file for whatever reason that we didn't think of, it will be put aside and not continuously attempt to process it.

Comment: So break down the processing of the file into small tasks. If a task is dangerous wrap the try catch around it. There is such a thing as too much `try-catch`.

Comment: How will that help if the exception is never going back to our code?